# how to understand es6 promise tree

Tags: ajax, promise, ecmascript-6

I have a complex ajax calling tree in my project.And I want to use `Promise`, the new feature of es6 to run away from callback hell.

It's hard to describe the whole calling tree so I made a simple example to simulate it:
[promise tree - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Halt/6g0mfgv8/7/)

In the example it's easy to tell that I ran into the `then` hell using `Promise`, and you can imagine if the tree keeps growing, it becomes impossible to understand it and modify it.

Here, I try my hand at solving this problem but I failed:[promise try failed - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Halt/v8agzsnn/2/)

And also, I've read something about the `Promise` but I don't think the promise chain's gonna solve this problem.Am I misunderstanding the usage of the promise chain?

Please help me and thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the code in your question?

Comment: That looks like a condition tree not a promise tree. You can't really avoid nesting for branching.

Comment: Voting to close - please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.And I noticed that @Bergi talked about the same issue.Why I use jsfiddle is to provide maximum convenience for answerers, you can either edit it in jsfiddle or you can copy the code into your IDE.Is there any trouble using jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't copy the whole ugly tree and force you to read it so I made a simple example to simulate it, and I think it's a minimal way to describe my problem.And I've even drawn a control flow graph to describe the structure of the tree but I can't post it since I have less than 10 reputations.I've tried my best for your better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First off, @Bergi's answer is spot on:

> That looks like a condition tree not a promise tree. You can't really avoid nesting for branching.
>
> -- Bergi

The way I like to make use of Promises is to use a library that takes a generator function and wraps it to behave nicely with promises:

Instead of:

```
task1().then(function (result) {
    // do something...
})
```

You do something like (the following uses the library [co](https://github.com/tj/co)):

```
co(function * () {
    try {
        let result = yield task1()
    } catch (e) {
        // handle errors
    }
})
```

Here's your example converted to using a generator function (JSBin doesn't support `co` so I used `Q.spawn` [Q is a promise library]): https://jsbin.com/gicicinawe/1/edit?js,output

**Notes**:

This assumes that your target JavaScript runtime supports generator functions.  [Currently, only Firefox and Chrome support generator functions](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-generators).

**Further Reading**:

- [Async/Await](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html)
- [The future of Promises in JavaScript](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/)

**Want to use this now and maintain compatibility with all current browsers?**

Then use [Babel](http://www.programwitherik.com/what-is-babel-the-javascript-compiler/)!

Comment: Hi Jrop, it's very nice of you to read my code and rewrite it with the Q library, I appriciate it very much.However what I've tried here is to avoid the hell thing, no matter it is the callback hell or then hell or try hell.Maybe @ Bergi is right, there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: When I use jquery, I've done some trick in my ajax calling function, so that even if there is a condition tree, I can still get rid of wrapping function with another one.

Comment: What do u think of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Halt/9bnpeaxg/)? Feel free to comment on it.

Comment: @Halt yeah I believe @ Bergi summed it up nicely, the reason you have a complex "tree" is because your *logic* has a complex tree structure.  Your promise callbacks honestly don't look like an example of callback-hell to me

Comment: [using jquery Deferred - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Halt/9bnpeaxg/)What I am talking about is this example, what do u think of this? Feel free to comment on it.

Comment: I've been using this trick in the jquery for a long time.Isn't it a clean and straightforward way to express the structure?